# How to recognize vertical swipe in iPad/iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, uigesturerecognizer, swipe

I have a custom view and when the user **SWIPES ON IT VERTICALLY ** (up or down), i want to present another view on it. I'v gone through UISwipeGestureRecognizer and found that it recognizes only left or right swipe. Is there any way where in i can recognize Vertical swipe and initiate a action based on it....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UISwipeGestureRecognizer supports up and down swipes

Comment: thanks for the answer ssj... I'm glad to know that it supports up and down swipes. Can you please tell me how to recognize these gestures..

Comment: somegesture.direction =  UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp